# Is there a registry key for setting default save location of application like notepad?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

How to set the default save location for notepad application (or any other application like word) to downloads folder, i.e whenever i try to save a file or open a file using notepad i want file explorer to open downloads folder under quick access or ThisPc. Is there any registry key that we can edit to set this save location

At the registry path **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders**, i have tried setting **Personal** Key to **%USERPROFILE%\Downloads**, but it didn't work.

Comment: This is most application dependent in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is no system-wide default parameter in Windows for the default
save location.

For example, for notepad the default is the folder that is found in
the `TEMP` environment variable.

Many other applications take their installation folder as the default.
An example here is Notepad++ whose default is the folder
`C:\Program Files\Notepad++`.

As another example, Microsoft Word uses as default
`C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents`.

Many applications have settings that allow specifying another folder
as default.

For example, Microsoft Word in menu *File > Options*, section Save,
allows to modify this default in the field "Default local f‌ile location".